# Can a bash script can decline the stop execution order from terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

Actually I am trying to create a password  protection for my terminal. Means when we start the terminal it will ask for password first.

But the problem is that if I press `CTRL + z` then the password script will stop.

How to fix this.

Comment: Hi ! As of now, you question needs more focus. Why did you tag your question `powershell` and `bash` ? one is for windows, the other is for linux.

Comment: What you are looking for is `trap`. Here is a similar question on [unix stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227459/make-a-process-unkillable-on-linux)

Comment: Also, a small tip : if you are storing your password in a text file somewhere, use a hashing program like `sha256sum` and compare the stored hash with the hashed input

Comment: Technically speaking, the script does not **stop**, but is suspended. The fact that the shell outputs _stopped_, is a bit misleading. You can bring it back to front via `fg`. Of course the interesting question is, **why** you press control-z, if you don't want to suspend it.

Answer (score 0):

use `trap` command:

```
trap 'printf "you can't do this"' SIGTSTP
```

Control+C sends SIGINT which will interrupt the application

Control+Z sends SIGTSTP